# Pointer arithmetics: strange result in C programm

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<cstdio>
int main(){
    int a=10,b=20;
    int *p=&a;
    *(p-1)=100;
    printf("%d, %d, %d\n",a,b,*(p-1));
//  printf("%d, %d, %d\n",&a,&b,(p-1));
    return 0;
}
```

Why does the first printf (line 6) show a different result whether or not the second one (line 7) is in comments or not?
I'm using C compiler (TDM-GCC 4.8.1 64bit)

Comment: `*(p-1)=100;` invokes undefined behavior,

Comment: What is this code supposed to do, in your mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p` is not pointing to an array, therefore the expression `*(p-1)` has [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). This means that, once `*(p-1)=100` has been executed, technically the program can behave in whatever way it likes.

What likely happens in practice is that you're overwriting some memory on the stack, which can lead to all sorts of side effects.

If you [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) your code, the tool will flag this up.

Comment: If `p` *were* pointing at (the first element of) an array, wouldn't it still be undefined behaviour (accessing outside array bounds)?

Comment: @Dmitri: It would. In logic terms, it sounds like you might be confusing [necessity with sufficiency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necessity_and_sufficiency#Relationship_between_necessity_and_sufficiency).

Comment: "Since `p` isn't pointing to an array" implies that the undefined behaviour exists because `p` isn't pointing at an array -- which isn't correct.  If `p` did point to an array, the problem would still be there.

Comment: @Dmitri: You are committing a common logical fallacy, called denying the antecedent http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denying_the_antecedent - This is well off-topic for this site, so I'd rather not spend more time on this (IMO pointless) debate.

Comment: No matter how many times you link to wikipedia it doesn't change the fact that you described the right effect but gave the wrong (or at least insufficiently described) cause.

Comment: @Dmitri: The way this site works is that anyone can post answers, and better answers generally tend to get upvoted and accepted. When I disagree with an answer, I often just post a better one. I think if you chose to do just that instead of starting confused debates in comments, IMO it would be a better use of your time and mine, and would only benefit this community.

Comment: @NPE: Um except he's right. The only one "confusing" and "debating" is you. And he's not _denying the antecedent_ whatsoever: read that article a bit more clearly. He's critiquing your argument, not providing an opposing one of his own.

Answer (score 1):

You code decrements what `p` points to and stores 100 there. Since `p` is initialized to the address of `a`, you are storing 100 at some random memory address.  I think you want:

```
*p = 100;
```

Comment: I don't think "random" means what you think it means.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to modify a memory location outside of the object `a` from which the pointer `p` is derived. The result is *undefined behavior* which means that *any* result is possible, even seemingly impossible ones.

The only way to give a definitive answer to your question is to inspect the assembler output from your compiler (if such output is obtainable), or the generated machine code. In this case, the object `a` will *typically* be allocated on a stack, and the presence of the other `printf` call *probably* changes the way the compiler allocates items on the stack inside the same code block.

Answer (score 1):

The replies by @valtah and @NPE are correct. If you look in even more detail about what is a happening you can see why:

If we look at the stack frame (or activation record) for this execution:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
   SP| saved state | return address |  a   |   b  |  p  |
-----------------------------------------------------|----
                                       ^             |
                                       |             |
                                       .-------------'
                                      &a
```

You will see that &a is the address of where `a` is stored on the stack and this is also assigned to `p`. When you use the value (p-1) it might compute the position elsewhere on the stack. (A good compiler would know that it was not an array pointer and give a semantic error at this point.) Many compilers would just compute the address. When you assign a value to it, it is possible that you are changing the value of one item away from the address of `a`. This could be `b` or it could be the *return address*. This then changes the execution state of the program.

This is exactly the mechanism that code injection attacks exploit to take control of systems. It is security violation code.

Now the question comes to mind. Where did that code come from? Are you writing it, or have you read it somewhere. It certainly tells the specialists about the kind of code you are working with...

:-)